# How to match a regExp when using toLocaleString() from javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regExp:

```
exp = new RegExp('^1');
```

and the following variables:

```
v1 = new Date();
v1 = v1.toLocaleString();

v2 = "10/9/2014 4:45:26 PM"; //Manually write the date.
```

Why do I get the following differences:?

```
v1.length == 33;
v2.length == 20;

v1.match(exp) == null;
v2.match(exp) != null;
```

NOTE: Just noticed that the issue only occurs in IE.

Comment: Is there some kind of closure involved? I notice you don't have `var`s declared. Not reproducible.

Comment: Why are you using regex to match when there is already a Date object? Extract data from the Date object and check against it.

Answer (score 0):

Method `toLocaleString()` formats the date according to locale settings, the closest locale format to yours is probably "en-US" so just use `toLocaleString("en-US")`